# Higher order function using Boolean as argument

Tags: javascript, boolean, higher-order-functions

I have been reading a book on JavaScript namely Eloquent JavaScript and I have come across the following function. I could not understand how it actually works?

```
function noisy(f) {

  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}
noisy(Boolean)(0);
// → calling with 0
// → called with 0 - got false
```

What kind of Argument is Boolean and what does passing two arguments one after another does it JavaScript. I would be thankful if anyone could explain how this is working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean is a built-in function/constructor, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean.

`f(x)(y)` means: Call `f`, passing `x` as an argument. Then take the returned value (which must be another function), and call that, passing `y` as an argument. It works like `var tmp = f(x); tmp(y);`.

`noisy(Boolean)` returns

```
function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
};
```

where `f` is bound to `Boolean`.

Then calling that function with `0` executes

```
console.log("calling with", arg);
var val = f(arg);
console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
return val;
```

where `f = Boolean` and `arg = 0`, i.e.

```
console.log("calling with", 0);
var val = Boolean(0);
console.log("called with", 0, "- got", val);
return val;
```

Comment: Thank you .. this was very easy to visualize!

Answer (score 2):

To address what I think your questions are:

- `Boolean` is a function — it's the standard constructor for the object wrapper type for boolean primitives;
- `noisy()` is a function that takes a function as its argument and returns another function;
- ... therefore calling `noisy(Boolean)` results in a function, so that function can be called with another parenthesized argument list.

So

```
noisy(Boolean)(0)
```

calls the `noisy()` function and then calls the returned function. The returned function logs messages (which I guess is why it's called "noisy") and shows what the originally-passed function (`Boolean`) does.

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean` is a javascript primitive type constructor

`noisy(Boolean)` would return the following function

```
function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = Boolean(arg); // <- see the Boolean here
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
}
```

so `noisy(Boolean)(0);` would execute the above function passing 0 as the argument 9arg)